# Noetherian ring whose ideals have arbitrarily large number of generators

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Does a commutative ring satisfying the following two properties exist?

1. All ideals are finitely generated;
2. There are prime ideals with arbitrarily large (finite) minimal generating sets.

Comment: This seems contradictory to me. A ring with the property that all ideals are finitely generated but the ring has ideals with arbitrarily large number of generators? Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: @anon271828: How is that contradictory?

Comment: @ChrisEagle: I don't see how an ideal can have finitely many generators AND infinitely many...

Comment: @anon271828 It looks like ast's phrasing misled you a bit. What Ast is asking about is: "is there a Noetherian ring such that for every $n\in \Bbb N$, there exists an ideal whose generating sets all have more than $n$ elements?" It is not a question about multiple generating sets for a single ideal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The example of [Nagata](https://books.google.ro/books?id=8kxlj48DWM4C&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=%22noetherian%20ring%22%20of%20%22infinite%20krull%20dimension%22&source=bl&ots=NpJZTifLtN&sig=od9XGIEXnRVCIs239nYJRLLK1zw&hl=ro&sa=X&ei=9yXzUO-JAtHKswbqrYCQCg#v=onepage&q=%22noetherian%20ring%22%20of%20%22infinite%20krull%20dimension%22&f=true) of a noetherian ring with infinite Krull dimension satisfies your requirements: all ideals are finitely generated and prime ideals must have arbitrarily large number of generators, otherwise their heights would be bounded, contradiction.

**Edit.** After posting this answer I wondered if a noetherian ring containing ideals with arbitrary large minimal generating sets has necessarily infinite Krull dimension. The answer is NO and [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-26/issue-4/On-the-unboundedness-of-generators-of-prime-ideals-in-powerseries/10.2969/jmsj/02640722.full) provides examples of prime ideals of height $2$ in the power series ring $K[[X,Y,Z]]$ having at least $n$ generators for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Is Nagata's example what you would call a ‘non-catenary ring’?